# How to change password (Hide & show) eye toggle Icon in Android?

Tags: android

I've tried with endIconDrawable but it's not working. Can someone help me?

```
 app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_password_selector"
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Material.io](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields)

> It is possible to set a custom Drawable as the text field's trailing
> icon via app:endIconMode="custom". You should specify a drawable and
> content description for the icon, and, optionally, specify custom
> behaviors.
>
> In the layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_check_circle_24dp"
    app:endIconContentDescription="@string/content_description_end_icon">
​
    ...
​
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm using                     
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
it's not working

Comment: I edited the question from the official reference, if that doesn't work you are doing it wrong. Try adding more info like your theme, material version that you are using, and your whole xml.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordEye3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:autofillHints="true" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and use your EditText as you wanted to use